# Recursively get meta data of FTP folder and all sub folders

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve metadata from an FTP folder and all sub folders. I want to get the file name, file size, and date/time (of when the file was modified). I found the sample code (below) online. I entered in my credentials, ran the code, and received this error: `No hostkey for host ftp.barra.com found.`
Is there a quick fix for this?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import time
import pysftp

ftp_username='xxx'
ftp_password='xxx'
ftp_host='xxx'

year = time.strftime("%Y")
month = time.strftime("%m")
day = time.strftime("%d")

ftp_dir = 'data/'+year+'/'+month

filename = time.strftime('ftp_file_lists.txt')
fout = open(filename, 'w')

wtcb = pysftp.WTCallbacks()

with pysftp.Connection(ftp_host, username=ftp_username, password=ftp_password) as sftp:
    sftp.walktree(ftp_dir, fcallback=wtcb.file_cb, dcallback=wtcb.dir_cb, ucallback=wtcb.unk_cb)
    print(len(wtcb.flist))
    for fpath in wtcb.flist:
        print(fpath, file=fout)
sftp.close()
```

Code from here.

http://alvincjin.blogspot.com/2014/09/recursively-fetch-file-paths-from-ftp.html

Comment: `pysftp` is for SFTP, the SSH file transfer protocol, not traditional FTP.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Ok, is there a way to run this kind of process given a traditional FTP folder?  I have a script that reads from on folder, and it works quite well.  I'd really like to get something that reads into all folders and sub-folders.  Thanks?